# After successfully compiling I get link time error in c++ program

Tags: c++

I have following five files. After successfully compiling them I receive linking errors. Please note: I don't want to use inheritance here.

> > one.cpp

```
#include"one.hpp"
#include"two.hpp"

void one::method()
{
    ptrTwoObj = new two;
    ptrTwoObj->method();
}
```

> > one.hpp

```
class one{
public:
void method();
};
```

> > two.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"two.hpp"
void two::method()
{
  std::cout<<"In class two"<<std::endl;
}
```

> > two.hpp

```
class two{
public:
    void method();
};

extern two *ptrTwoObj;
```

> > main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"bsap.hpp"

int main()
{
    one *ptrOneObj = new one;
    ptrOneObj->method();
}
```

> > I compiled above files with following command

```
`g++ one.cpp two.cpp main.cpp`
```

> And following are the linking errors

```
`/tmp/ccwE53uC.o: In function `one::method()':
one.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `ptrTwoObj'
one.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `ptrTwoObj'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
```

Comment: `extern two *ptrTwoObj;` Is nowhere defined in the code you're showing.

Comment: And you don't need to pass headers to the `g++`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying call two::method from inside one::method. Do you have any suggestion how  one::method can be made visible in two::method?